# How to make a line with a laser pointer

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, geometry

So I was going through a meandering "thought journey" and was thinking about human's [persistence of vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision).  This can be demonstrated by rapidly moving a laser pointer back and forth, which tricks the human brain into seeing a solid line.  This works, since the "point" of the laser inst actually a cartesian point, but a circle with measurable width.  Then I was thinking there are actual ways to make a line with the laser pointer.  These are the ones I can think of:

1. Hold the end of a laser pointer on the edge of a piece of paper (with a slight angle) and the width of the beam will form a line down the paper
2. Curve the paper and the width of the beam will form a line, relative to the angle of the beam and the curve of the paper
3. Reflect the laser pointer off a straight or curved surface and it will create a line down the paper (Technically, this would work, but seems just an alternate way to do 1 and 2)
4. Use a prism to break the laser into its separate wavelengths (I assume this would technically work, but not be visible)

Are there any other ways to make a line with a laser pointer?

-- I hope this isnt off topic here.  But this seemed the most likely place on StackExchange to get the right answer.

Comment: Point 4. Lasers are usually made to be monochromatic as best as possible so there isn't much that can be split per se. But you are close with some form of diffraction if you've ever encountered those laser pointer caps that modify the beams into shapes which includes lines.

Comment: @Triatticus I had one of those laser pointers with the caps long ago.  I thought about that, but I kind of thought of that as cheating, as you are modifying the source of the laser

Comment: A cylindrical lens does it, or a plano-convex lens tilted at a very steep angle.

Comment: @Keltari you are only modifying the beam after it leaves the laser, it's basically the same as your prism idea. But actually does what you want.

Comment: You can buy this at any hardware store:  a level with a builtin laser pointer that can be set to scan across the current axis

Comment: @CarlWitthoft i own 2 different types of those levels.   They use method 2.  Im looking for other methods/

Comment: I do not understand your type 2, unless if you mean the same as type 1, but just with a curve instead of a straight line, which to me is the same method. But the simplest bubble levels that project a line simply have a diffraction element in front of the beam that makes it into a line. The more advanced use the eye persistence and scan the beam, which actually feels totally unnecessary unless if you require field programmable shapes. And the caps are not cheating, laser is the same you just diffract light (with the prism you refract).

Comment: (like @S.McGrew said a cylindrical lens achieves that and I believe, although i might be mistaken that the diffractive element in the line bubble levels is just a Fresnel lens equivalent to a cylindrical lens, as those are hyper cheap to make out of plastic.)

Comment: Actually, it is very easy to make a diffractive element to produce a line from a laser pointer.  It's essentially a hologram of a line about half the length of the desired line length.  No reference beam is used.  These elements are, indeed, very easy and inexpensive to make in plastic.